# Can I replace an electric range with a cooktop and separate oven?

Tags: electrical, oven

I'm replacing an electric range with a cooktop and separate oven. I know an electric range runs off of one 220V power source. Do I have to run a separate 220V line from the fuse box to my kitchen for the oven since the cooktop already has one, or can they both run off of the same 220V power source? It seems to me that they should both be able to run off the same power source and be wired together. I don't see why they would have to be separate but I need to confirm this.

Comment: Firs you need to tell us the ratings of the new appliances and the size/rating of the existing circuit.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to have a second 220V outlet installed, even if it's on the same circuit (which probably calls for a pro)... beyond that, if the total maximum draw of the new equipment is less than or equal to what the circuit is rated/breakered for, you should be OK.

Comment: Actually the total draw can be higher than the circuit rating. Household cooking appliances use a demand factor and not the actual rating of the appliance. So for instance if the combined wattage of both units is less than 12kW then the circuit can be shared. Thing is, this is not as easy as it seems, especially for a DIYer. Running a new circuit will likely be much safer and easier.

Comment: Yes, you really need to specify the TYPE of wire, i.e., aluminum with shielded ground, how many conductors and the size e.g., #6 Awg. As well as the load requirements of the new appliances.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the ampacity of the existing 220VAC branch circuit is sufficient to support the new cooking equipment, you can do this, despite it not being called out explicitly as allowed for by the NEC.  The closest cites I can find in the Code for this are 210.19(A)(3) Exception 1:

> *Exception No.1: Conductors tapped from a 50-ampere branch circuit supplying 
>   electric ranges, wall-mounted electric ovens, and counter-mounted electric 
>   cooking units shall have an ampacity of not less than 20 amperes and shall be 
>   sufficient for the load to be served. These tap conductors include any 
>   conductors that are a part of the leads supplied with the appliance that are 
>   smaller than the branch-circuit conductors. The taps shall not be longer 
>   than necessary for servicing the appliance.*

210.23(C):

> **40- and 50-Ampere Branch Circuits.** A 40- or 50-ampere branch circuit shall 
>   be permitted to supply cooking appliances that are fastened in place in any 
>   occupancy. In other than dwelling units, such circuits shall be permitted to 
>   supply fixed lighting units with heavy-duty lampholders, infrared heating 
>   units, or other utilization equipment.

and Table 220.52, Notes 3 and 4 (reformatted to use decimals instead of improper fractions for kilowattage):

> 3. Over 1.75 kW through 8.75 kW. In lieu of the method provided in Column C, 
>      it shall be permissible to add the nameplate ratings of all household cooking 
>      appliances rated more than 1.75 kW but not more than 8.75 kW and multiply the 
>      sum by the demand factors specified in Column A or Column B for the given 
>      number of appliances. Where the rating of cooking appliances falls under both 
>      Column A and Column B, the demand factors for each column shall be applied to 
>      the appliances for that column, and the results added together.
> 4. Branch-Circuit Load. It shall be permissible to calculate the branch-
>      circuit load for one range in accordance with Table 220.55. The branch-circuit 
>      load for one wall-mounted oven or one counter-mounted cooking unit shall be 
>      the nameplate rating of the appliance. The branch-circuit load for a counter-
>      mounted cooking unit and not more than two wall-mounted ovens, all supplied 
>      from a single branch circuit and located in the same room, shall be calculated 
>      by adding the nameplate rating of the individual appliances and treating this 
>      total as equivalent to one range.

Comment: three phase has the correct answer, my only caution is the tap (if you use smaller wire) should be in conduit from the junction box to the oven , if the same sized wire is used conduit is not needed.